# Could not run Flutter project. Could not find an option named "dart-define"

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project and I have run it, everything is fine for a moment. But after some run, an error occurred. I cannot run my flutter project again, this is the error message

```
Could not find an option named "dart-define".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

How to fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: can you share screenshot of code with error in terminal

Comment: sorry for my very late response. Which code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problems, I accidentally rename my Flutter SDK to "flutter ". So I just rename my Flutter SDK back to "flutter" and restart my Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect but it works for me in android.

Run a command `flutter run --dart-define ...`

Instead of `flutter build <platform> --dart-define ...`